# how to inactive sigma js node hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code i na js file:

```
function create() {
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('neighbors', function (nodeId) {
    var k,
        neighbors = {},
        index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

    for (k in index)
        neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

    return neighbors;
});

sigma.parsers.gexf(
    '/resources/js/arctic.gexf',
    {
        container: 'zarf',
        settings: {

        }
    },
    function (s) {
        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function (n) {
            n.originalColor = n.color;
        });
        s.graph.edges().forEach(function (e) {
            e.originalColor = e.color;
        });

        s.bind('clickNode', function (e) {
            var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
                toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
            toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;
            //***************************
            if ($("#lab").childElementCount != 0) {
                $("#lab").children().remove();
            }
            $("#lab").append('<li>' +
                e.data.node.label);
            $.each(toKeep, function (key, value) {               

                $("#lab").append('<ul>' + '<li>' +
                    key +
                    '</li>'
                    + '</ul>')
            });
            $("#lab").append(
                '</li>')


            s.graph.nodes().forEach(function (n) {
                if (toKeep[n.id])
                    n.color = n.originalColor;
                else
                    n.color = '#eee';
            });
            s.graph.edges().forEach(function (e) {
                if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target])
                    e.color = e.originalColor;
                else
                    e.color = '#eee';
            });
            s.refresh();
        });

        s.bind('clickStage', function (e) {
            s.graph.nodes().forEach(function (n) {
                n.color = n.originalColor;
            });
            $("#lab").children().remove();
            s.graph.edges().forEach(function (e) {
                e.color = e.originalColor;
            });
            s.refresh();
        });

        s.bind('overNode', function (e) {
            var label = e.data.node.label;

        });
        s.bind('outNode', function (e) {
            $("#tt").remove();
        })
    }
);
}
```

this is sigma js sample.

I want to inactive node hover.

or I want to design an tooltip my self and add other data to that.

I think that must add some code between 'settings{ }' in line 18. but I don't know how to do that.

how I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

add `enableHovering: false` to `settings` to disable it.

a full list of the settings can be found at https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/wiki/Settings